# Error "rollbackFailedOptional" on create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, cmd

I'm learning React. I got this 2 errors in the screenshots below (links) when running:

```
npm i -g create-react-app@1.5.2
```

- Screenshots:

https://i.ibb.co/S7yszvz/Capture.png

https://i.ibb.co/4Y7LY6X/Capture2.png

- The errors:

  ```
  [..................] / rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 8a15f24eef6f3714

  npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
  npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
  npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app 
  failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.21.30.247:80
  npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
  npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
  npm ERR! network
  npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
  npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
  ```

What I tried:

- npm config rm proxy
- npm config rm https-proxy
- npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
- npm config get https-proxy (returns **null**)

I'm hoping for some help so I can make progress. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I finally did it using my phone network (must have been the firewall), but then:

```
C:\UserXXXX\Desktop\js REACT>create-react-app react-app

Creating a new React app in C:\UserXXXX\\Desktop\js REACT\react-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/posix-character- 
classes/-/posix-character-classes-0.1.1.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 
registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\UserXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12- 
11T10_28_30_314Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting react-app / from C:\UserXXXX\Desktop\js REACT
Done.
```

Comment: Thank you,  I was having the same problem :)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issue a while back with `npx create-react-app my-app` as well.
So I reinstalled NodeJs and then tried removing proxy set up from npm config by following commands:

- `npm init`
- `npm config rm proxy`
- `npm config rm https-proxy`

and then try the command `npm i -g create-react-app@X.X.X` again.